# Python: How to print all numbers except the multiples of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In trying to print all numbers except multiples of `3` until 10, this program does not shows any output:

```
a = 1 

for a in range (1,10) :
    if a % 3 == 0:
        continue
    a+=1
    
    print (a)
    a+=1
```

Comment: 6 is a multiple of 3 and study loops in python

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: No need to initialise `a`, and `a+=1` is unnecessary.  The loop and `range` do this already.

Comment: Remove all the `a+=1` and you'd basically be there

Answer (score 2):

You would just need this much code:

```
for a in range (1,10) :
    if a % 3 == 0:
        continue
    print (a)
```

You do not need to declare the variable that you are using as a variable that holds values from the range while using for loop.
Also, you don't need to increment the value of the variable yourself, it is done for you by the loop.

You can study more about loops [Python Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm)

**NOTE:** We do not even need to use **continue** if we use negated condition in **if** as @S3DEV answer has.

Comment: Friendly observation: `continue` is not needed, and inefficient in this case.  All that is required is a negative `if`.

Comment: true that @S3DEV I am just trying to keep the code aligned to the one in question as I thought he is seeking what's wrong with his code and not the usual type of question on StackOverflow which are seeking for an answer...I hope you get my point... But for what its worth, I will add it to answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify to:

```
for a in range(1,10):
    if a % 3 != 0:
        print(a)
```

Comment: you are incrementing a manually, which is also done by the loop for you... hence in a single iteration, you are moving more steps ahead than just 1 @LEEVANCESINGH

Comment: @LEEVANCESINGH - My pleasure mate.  The comments are referring to the *nature* of the question and (it appears) that with a little more effort and research, you very likely could have solved this yourself. I would recommend reviewing the links in the comment; TBH I remind myself of these from time to time.